# Does scons support verbose mode and asian language?

Tags: printing, character, scons, verbose

1. I tried

   ```
    scons --verbose
    scons -verbose
   ```

   Seems both gave me the version information, not the verbose mode. I wish to look into some more details on how scons build my project. Is there a command line for this?
2. I know python support asian language, no problem

   ```
   $ python
   Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 17 2016, 23:03:43)
   [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> print '妳好'
   妳好
   ```

   I tried inside my SConscript

   ```
   print "妳好".
   ```

   scons prints some error:

   ```
   SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe5' in file /home/abc/SConstruct on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
   ```

I wish to know if SCons supports asian languages in its print?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: Does SCons support --verbose?

A1: No see the man page or use scons -h to see all supported flags
http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html

Q2: Does SCons support foreign languages?

A2: You're questions might be better asked as "Does SCons support unicode?".  In which case the answer is Not Really. But we're working on python 3 port which should